# Equality Test Fails with Mongoose .lean() Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to compare `req.user._id` with an array of ObjectIds returned from a MongoDB query. But all `.includes()`, strict, and loose equality checks failed.

Here is the logic in my controller (truncated for simplicity):

```js
// Get the ID of the document from the request
const someDocId = req.body.id;

// Perform the search with projection
const result = await Some_DB.findById(someDocId,{adminIds:1, _id:0}).lean();

/*
The structure of the query result is as the following:
{
  adminIds: [ 5f77ba7d1a0fba8f5e811e76, 6035f2e7174d4961808944d1 ],
}

And req.user._id is equal to 6035f2e7174d4961808944d1
*/

// When I do
console.log(result.adminIds[1] === req.user._id);
console.log(result.adminIds[1] == req.user._id);
console.log(result.adminIds.includes(req.user._id))

// I also tried
const { ObjectId, } = require('mongoose').Types
console.log(result.adminIds[1] === ObjectId(req.user._id));
console.log(result.adminIds[1] == ObjectId(req.user._id));
console.log(result.adminIds.includes(ObjectId(req.user._id)))

// The result is always false


// Additional Info: 
(the results below are the same with or without .lean()

const { ObjectId, } = require('mongoose').Types
const a = sphereInfo.adminIds[1];
const b = req.user._id; 
console.log(a instanceof ObjectId); // => true
console.log(b instanceof ObjectId); // => true

console.log(typeof(result.adminIds[1])); // => object
console.log(typeof(req.user._id)); // => object

console.log(result.adminIds[1]); 
// 6035f2e7174d4961808944d1 (note:there is no single quote around)
console.log(req.user._id); 
// 6035f2e7174d4961808944d1 (note:there is no single quote around)


const a = Object.values(sphereInfo.adminIds[1]);
const b = Object.values(req.user._id);
console.log(a); // => [ 'ObjectID', <Buffer 60 35 f2 e7 17 4d 49 61 80 89 44 d1> ]
console.log(b); // => [ 'ObjectID', <Buffer 60 35 f2 e7 17 4d 49 61 80 89 44 d1> ]

const a = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(sphereInfo.adminIds[1]);
const b = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(req.user._id);
console.log(a); // => [ '_bsontype', 'id' ]
console.log(b); // => [ '_bsontype', 'id' ]

console.log(Object.entries(sphereInfo.adminIds[1]));
console.log(Object.entries(req.user._id));
/*
Result:
[
  [ '_bsontype', 'ObjectID' ],
  [ 'id', <Buffer 60 35 f2 e7 17 4d 49 61 80 89 44 d1> ]
]
[
  [ '_bsontype', 'ObjectID' ],
  [ 'id', <Buffer 60 35 f2 e7 17 4d 49 61 80 89 44 d1> ]
]
*/

console.log(JSON.stringify(sphereInfo.adminIds[1]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.user._id));
/*
Result:
"6035f2e7174d4961808944d1"
"6035f2e7174d4961808944d1"
*/
```

```js
// After removing .lean()
console.log(result.adminIds[1] === req.user._id); // => false
console.log(result.adminIds[1] == req.user._id); // => false
console.log(result.adminIds.includes(req.user._id)) // => true
```

The schema (truncated for simplicity):

```js
// Dependencies
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const SomeSchema = new Schema({

    adminIds: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
    }],

}, {
    collection: 'SomeCollection',
    timestamps: true,
});

module.exports = { SomeSchema, };
```

Whichever way I look at it, they are exactly identical. However, all `.includes()`, strict, and loose equality check returns false. What further confuses me is that the object structure is the same with or without `.lean()`
If I remove `.lean()` from the query, all checks still failed, only `.inclides()` return true.

According to the Mongoose [Doc.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html) :

> The lean option tells Mongoose to skip hydrating the result documents. This makes queries faster and less memory intensive, but the result documents are plain old JavaScript objects (POJOs), not Mongoose documents. By default, Mongoose queries return an instance of the Mongoose Document class. Documents are much heavier than vanilla JavaScript objects because they have a lot of internal state for change tracking. Enabling the lean option tells Mongoose to skip instantiating a full Mongoose document and just give you the POJO.

The doc also mentioned that the downside of enabling lean is that lean docs don't have:

- Change tracking
- Casting and validation
- Getters and setters
- Virtuals
- save()

There is nowhere I can see that `.lean()` can affect the equality checks as well as the `.includes()` method.
So finally the question is can someone explain to me how does `.lean()` causes the equality checks to fail but `.includes` to pass?
Note: I am not asking how to compare them so the check will pass, but how does `.lean()` cause the checks to fail but `.includes() to pass.

Comment: If you print both values they are the same? Print their types as well.

Comment: @MinusFour I did. `console.log(typeof(result.adminIds[1])); // => object
console.log(typeof(req.user._id)); // => object`

Comment: Then your result structure in the post is misleading. These are both different objects most likely, hence why equality checks fails. What's the structure of the objects?

Comment: If you are getting that output on the console then the documentation of `lean` is lying or at the very least I wouldn't consider them POJOs. Do `Object.entries` of both objects or  `JSON.stringify` it. That will let you know more about the object structure.

Comment: @MinusFour, I have edited the question with the info. you specified.

Comment: I ran a test on my local mongodb and node with the same exact schema (array of ObjectIds) and `lean` or not, it makes no difference, the comparison without casting ObjectIds to string fails.

Comment: @codemonkey are you using the native MongoDB driver or mongoose?

Comment: I am using mongoose. Never used native and am not familiar with it.

Comment: @codemonkey i made a mistake in my question. Not all check passes, but `.includes()` return true after removing `.lean()`. AFAIK, `.includes()` uses strict equality as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is subtle, but it exists. With `.lean()` your query eventually resolves with array in `result.adminIds`; the caveat is that each element of this array is ObjectId - which, as @codemonkey correctly mentioned, remains ObjectId - an object. And when you try to find a particular ObjectId in that array with `includes`, the search just has to fail because of reference non-equality.

However, when query is executed as is, without `.lean()` applied, `result.adminIds` is no longer just an Array - it's [MongooseArray](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/array.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray) that has a lot of array methods essentially overridden. And that's how [Mongoose.prototype.indexOf](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/94a2a7f8ba553448fb7598b0108a6046b238e44d/lib/types/core_array.js#L481) (which is used in [MongooseArray.prototype.includes](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/94a2a7f8ba553448fb7598b0108a6046b238e44d/lib/types/core_array.js#L466)) looks like:

```
indexOf(obj, fromIndex) {
  if (obj instanceof ObjectId) {
    obj = obj.toString();
  }

  fromIndex = fromIndex == null ? 0 : fromIndex;
  const len = this.length;
  for (let i = fromIndex; i < len; ++i) {
    if (obj == this[i]) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

As you can see, the very first step here is transforming the first parameter (if it's ObjectId) to string, essentially eliminating reference checks. That's why `includes` should work both for direct string comparison and for ObjectId one.

But the funniest part follows: because `==` (and not `===`) is used in lookups, ObjectId values stored in that array get casted to primitives when compared with string. That's why even though direct comparison gives you `false`, `includes()` actually provides you with convenient (but confusing, true) workaround.

Comment: This clears things up a lot. But according to MDN Web Doc, "includes() uses the sameValueZero algorithm to determine whether the given element is found", which will always return false if comparing objects. But arrays are objects as well.

Comment: MongooseArray has `includes()` method overriden as well.

Comment: So does the mongoose version of `.includes()` uses the mongoose version of `.indexOf()` as well? Was checking the mongoose doc via the link you embedded in MongooseArray. Seems like they are independent.

Comment: @AvivLo `const ret = this.indexOf(obj, fromIndex);` means using `MongooseArray`'s version of indexOf, not array's one.

Comment: Thanks. You made my day. The last bits of your answer really brings out stuff that normal people won't bother to dig into. Your effort is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why the documentation insist they are POJOs but the results you are getting do match up with [MongoDB ObjectID](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) objects. Maybe they say they are POJOs because they are not being constructed by their relevant constructors and they are just properties being passed down to a new object.

You want to compare the `str` property if you want to compare the hex value you see on your console.

```
console.log(result.adminIds[1].str === req.user._id.str);
```

Otherwise, you are comparing two different objects (which is always false).

The only way this would check true:

```
console.log(result.adminIds[1] === req.user._id);
```

Would be if they are both the same object or they are both the same string.

**In my opinion**

I wouldn't call an Object that extends `valueOf` and/or `toString` a POJO as it's essentially extending SOME functionality of JS objects. Hence, not plain anymore.

Comment: Thanks. I know that comparing objects in javascript will always return false unless both refer to the same instance or same memory location. But even if perform the query without `.lean()`, MongoDB is still returning me with objects but the equality checks still pass.

Comment: Yes, but like the documentation says these objects are heavily extended for convenience. So they add a lot of "magic" through getters and setters. Try checking the type of both object properties with `lean` and without `lean`. If the check passes, you will most likely see different types or the  `getter` is smart enough to return an existing objectid.

Comment: Edit:  not all equality checks pass after removing `.lean()`, only `.includes()` does.

Comment: Both of the `includes`?

Comment: Just the one after removing `.lean()`

Comment: @AvivLo Are you implying `result.adminIds.includes(req.user._id)` works, but `result.adminIds[1] === req.user._id` doesn't?

Comment: yes exactly. After removing .lean() . Otherwise all of them are returning false.

Answer (score 1):

`lean()` will return POJOs, but the ObjectId values will still be of type Object.
The results of your own test confirm that:

```
console.log(typeof(result.adminIds[1])); // => object
console.log(typeof(req.user._id)); // => object
```

As such, to compare those two values, you would just need to compare like so:

```
console.log(result.adminIds[1].toString() === req.user._id.toString());
```

At least that what I always do and it always works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I should make the question clearer, I am not asking how do I compare them so I can get the check to pass, but how does .lean cause the check to fail.